# asp.net core run while(true) in separate process

Tags: asp.net, while-loop

I want to run a method which will always running like:

```
public async Task GetMessageUpdatesAsync()
{    
    while(true)
    {
        await GetUpdatesAsync();
    }
}
```

I want to run it in separate process. while my app continue run.

How ca I do it?

**Update**:

here is my method code

```
    public static async Task<string> GetUpdatesAsync()
    {
        string telegramToken = "Token";
        var botClient = new TelegramBotClient(telegramToken);
        int? updateId=null;
        while (true) // this will not break
        {
           var updates = await botClient.GetUpdatesAsync(updateId);
           foreach(var update in updates)
           {
               //do some thing
               updateId = update.Id + 1;
           }
        }
    }
```

I want previous method running while other website code working (like get information from database, update database information ...).

- List item

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Are you trying something else, like running this multiple times at once? You can use Parallel.For This seems to be a XY problem

Comment: Please see update to question

Comment: I understand now. Yep, it was a XY problem. In any case I think your question is useful to understand how and why it works the while(forever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ASP.NET` (web app) is not made to work for ever. Is only to work with a quick response to some request.

You should create two projects to do this. There is no work or improvement added do it in the same project.

If you are in windows, you can use a `WinForm` (desktop app) or `Console App` but the ideal to do this is create a `service` and running trough `services.msc` for ever.

If you are in linux, I would do a `Service` as a daemon to work with systemctl in e.g., or a `Console` and run it with a `cron task`.

Then if you wanna still do your stuff in an `ASP.NET` like a `Web API` you can call from that service to the API with `HttpClient` like `RestSharp Client` (you can get it from nuget), and then do the specific and finite task.

Comment: What is best to my situation? Any Example code?

Comment: @Munt I didn't put any code because the code is right, the problem is your architecture. You have to create a service like this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-windows-services-in-c-sharp/

Comment: It's not a good practice to put the code in same web project so I have to create a service... but in my VS I have seen Worker Service??

Comment: Is there any other link that can be more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hosted service to run as a background service and updates the value while the api is running

Create a backgroundService Class:

**Worker.cs**

```cs
    public class Worker:BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IList<string> _list;

        public Worker(IList<string> list)
        {
            _list = list;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                await GetUpdatesAsync();
        }

        private async Task GetUpdatesAsync()
        {
            _list.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            //Delay in milliseconds between each update
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

In your **Startup.cs** add the hosted service and a singleton instance that will be updated by it, in this example we are modifing an List

```cs
//...rest of startup

services.AddSingleton<IList<string>, List<string>>();
services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

And in your Controller/Service you need to receive the same instance of the **cached** object

Answer (score 0):

you can use Quartz scheduler.

[Quartz scheduler](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/aspnet-core-integration.html)